# Permutations Finder Help Number 2

Tags: java, homework, combinatorics

Previous question:

[Java application for finding permutations efficiently](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/java-application-for-finding-permutations-efficiently)>

I have changed quite a bit of code, and need some more reviews.

```
class Permutations {

    static long factorial(int num){
        long factorial = num;
        for (int forBlockvar = num; forBlockvar > 1; forBlockvar--) {
            factorial = factorial * forBlockvar;
        }
        return factorial / num;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        long FactNmR;
        int n = 8;
        int num = n;
        int r = 6;
        int nMr = n - r;

        long FactN = factorial(num);

        if (nMr == 2) {
            FactNmR = 2;
        }
        else if (nMr <= 1){
            FactNmR = 1;
        }
        else if (nMr >= 2) {
            num = nMr;
            FactNmR = factorial(num);
        }

        long permutations = FactN;

        permutations = permutations / FactNmR;

        System.out.println(permutations);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you pasted it well? It's not compiling, I think the `return` statement of the `factorial` method is in a wrong place.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out that the return statement has to be outside of the brackets of the factorial method.  Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code comment:

```
static long factorial(int num){
    long factorial = num;
    for (int forBlockvar = num; forBlockvar > 1; forBlockvar--) {
        factorial = factorial * forBlockvar;
    }
    return factorial / num;
}
```

You are starting your `factorial = num`, then multiplying it by `num` in the first iteration of the loop, then dividing by `num` at the end.  Starting with `factorial = 1`, or starting  `forBlockvar = num - 1` (I prefer the second) will remove the need to divide at the end.  You can also return 1 if the input is less than 2.

```
static long factorial(int num){
    if(num < 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    long factorial = num;
    for (int forBlockvar = num - 1; forBlockvar > 1; forBlockvar--) {
        factorial = factorial * forBlockvar;
    }
    return factorial;
}
```

You could also implement this function recursively.

```
static long factorial(int num){
    if(num < 2) {
        return 1;
    }
    return num * factorial(num - 1);
}
```

### General:

What do you mean by finding the permutations of 2 numbers?  There are 2 permutations of 2 numbers [x, y]: [x, y] and [y, x].

**EDIT**

I think I know what you are trying to do now... You want to know how many permutations are available by selecting `r` objects out of a total of `n`.

The basic formula for that is `n! / (n-r)!`.  However, this means calculating the factorial of `(n-r)` twice (in our example, we have `8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1 / 2*1`, but with a lower `r` the overlap will be greater).

Instead of calculating the complete factorial for both numerator and denominator, there is a way to calculate the value of the numerator such that the denominator is always going to be 1.  That means we eliminate one factorial calculation, and reduce the other.  I'm going to let you think about it a bit before just giving the answer.

**EDIT 2**

Since you have figured out what I was hinting at, I'll explain it further.

`n!` can be represented as `n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)...(2)*(1)`.  When `r` is less than `n` and greater than `0`, `n!` can be then be represented as `n*(n-1)*(n-2)...(n-r+1)*(n-r)*(n-r-1)*(n-r-2)...(2)*(1)`.

`(n-r)!` is `(n-r)*(n-r-1)*(n-r-2)...(2)*(1)`.

Therefore, our numerator is `n*(n-1)*(n-2)...(n-r+1)*(n-r)*(n-r-1)*(n-r-2)...(2)*(1)`, and our denominator is `(n-r)*(n-r-1)*(n-r-2)...(2)*(1)`.  Cancelling like terms, we have `n!/(n-r)! = n*(n-1)*(n-2)...(n-r+1)`.

```
static long permute(int totalItems, int numToPick) {
    long permutations = totalItems;
    while (--numToPick > 0) {
        permutations *= --totalItems;
    }
    return permutations;
}
```

You should ensure that `0 < numToPick <= totalItems`, and `totalItems > 0`.

Comment: +1. Please note that the second (`forBlockvar = num - 1`) gives result `0` for input `0` (instead of `1`, `0! = 1`).

Comment: @palacsint good point.  Updated answer.

Comment: So, @ChrisMarasti-Georg, what you are meaning is canceling similar terms, right?

Comment: @CodeAdmiral Yes, exactly.

Comment: Otay, that helps a bunch.

Comment: Problem is, I still get an error:                         Main.java:48: variable FactNmR might not have been initialized
?????

Comment: That error is because the compiler is not allowed to determine that all code paths assign a value to FactNmR before it is read.  You can initialize it `long FactNmR = 0`, or have an `else` with no `if` at the end of the branch that assigns a value.

Comment: Otay, thank you again, @ChrisMarasti-Georg

Answer (score 2):

CodeAdmiral,

I think I would find the program most readable like this:

**The straightforward way:**

```
class Permutations {

    static long factorial(int n) {
        long f = 1;
        while (n > 0) f *= n--;
        return f;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n = 8, k = 6;
        long permutations = factorial(n) / factorial(n-k);
        System.out.println(permutations);
    }
}
```

Of course, this method is less efficient -- and also more prone to overflow -- than the more direct method of computing the result without wasted operations. So, a cleaner way would be like this:

**The more efficient way:**

```
class Permutations {

    static long permutations(int n, int k) {
        long p = 1;
        while (k-- > 0) p *= n--;
        return p;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n = 8, k = 6;
        System.out.println(permutations(n, k));
    }
}
```

Tying it all together with a version that also computes n choose k (combinations) gives the following:

**Computing both permutations and combinations:**

```
class Permutations {

    static long factorial(int n) {
        long f = 1;
        while (n > 0) f *= n--;
        return f;
    }

    static long permutations(int n, int k) {
        long p = 1;
        while (k-- > 0) p *= n--;
        return p;
    }

    static long combinations(int n, int k) {
        long a = 1, b = 1;
        while (k > 0) { a *= n--; b *= k--; }
        return a / b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n = 8, k = 6;
        System.out.println(
            "Permutations: " + permutations(n, k) + " = " +
            factorial(n) / factorial(n-k));
        System.out.println(
            "Combinations: " + combinations(n, k) + " = " +
            factorial(n) / factorial(k) / factorial(n-k));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you!  Not meaning to be a hater or anything, but for the math, I want to fully understand how to reach the solution.  Your answer was amazing.  +1

Answer (score 1):

It looks much better and it's more easier to read than the previous post. Some small notes below.

In the `factorial` method you should assign `1` to the `factorial` variable in the first line, so you don't have to divide it with `num` in the last line.

```
    static long factorial(int num) {
        long factorial = 1;
        ...
        return factorial;
    }
```

It would result more simple and easier to read code and it gives proper result for `0`.

After that you should reduce the `if-else if-else-if` structure since the `factorial` method now gives proper result for 
`2`, `1` and `0`.

---

You could call the `factorial` method with `nMr` in this part:

```
num = nMr;
FactNmR = factorial(num);
```

---

Based on the classic

```
P(n, k) = n! / ((n - k)!)
```

formula, I'd create one variable for only one thing with these names:

- `n`, `k` for the input values,
- `diff` would be the result of `n - k`,
- `dividend` would be the result of `n!`,
- `divisor` would be the result of `dividend!`.

The `n` and `k` are the most important. Anyway, put the formula in a comment with the used variable names. It would help the readers a lot.

Comment: Yes, I have since fixed this, thank you so much.  +1